# How to get a type from a TypeVar?

Tags: typing, python-3.9

Supose that I have:

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Client')

Now, I want a function that gets the type T and returns 'Client', or, yet better a class Client.

How I can get it in Python 3.9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so via `typing_inspect.get_bound` from the [`typing_inspect`](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect) package. It offers cross-version support for runtime inspection of type annotations:

```
>>> class Foo: pass

>>> T = TypeVar("T", bound=Foo)
>>> typing_inspect.get_bound(T)
__main__.Foo

>>> T = TypeVar("T", bound="Foo")
>>> typing_inspect.get_bound(T)
ForwardRef('Foo')
```

When `bound` is set to a string, the returned value is a "forward reference". I don't think there's currently a public API to evaluate that to a concrete class. There is a private API that you could use like this:

```
>>> ref = typing_inspect.get_bound(T)
>>> ref._evaluate(globals(), globals(), set())
__main__.Foo
```

Comment: Supose that I have  x: T  Then, I can do x.__bound__.__forward_arg__ to get 'Client'. But I still do not found a way to get it as a class.

Comment: Using x.__bound__._evaluate like you pointed worked but needs to pass the module in string like 'model.Client' instead of just 'Client'

Comment: Thank you for your help. The use of evaluate can solve my problem.

Comment: @FernandoLima The point of using `typing_inspect` in favor of `__bound__` is that it provides a stable public API that works across Python versions. There is no guarantee that `__bound__` works in past versions and will work in future versions, as it's not part of the standard. For the other question, it seems that you've already made it work, so it'd be great if you could accept the answer.

Comment: Done. I am sorry, I forgot to confirm that I accepted the answer. I should have already done this.

Comment: @FernandoLima No problem, appreciated!